# Method of characteristics - Component transport

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Problem: Assume that a Component mass Conservation Equation is given by $\phi \frac{\partial c}{\partial t} + u \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = -rc$ , where $r=constant$.

Solve the Equation using Method of characteristics.

I know how to solve this problem when it is equal to zero on R.H.S, but struggling to find a solution when $-rc$ is given on R.H.S.

Any ideas?

Comment: The system of characteristic differential equations is : $$\frac{dt}{\phi}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dc}{-r}$$

Comment: I get the following system of differential Equations:
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} = u$ 
$\frac{\partial t}{\partial s} = \phi$
$\frac{\partial h}{\partial s} = -rh$ 

Then solving them gives: 
$x = us + x_0$
$t = \phi s$ 
$h = h_0 e^{-rs}$ 

And I end up with this: 
$c(x(s),t(s)) = c(x_0 , 0) e^{rs}$ 

Do I need any initial conditions to get the proper answer?

Comment: What is the question exactly ? Solving the PDE for the general solution ? If so, no condition is specified. Or solving the DPE for a particular solution with respect to some condition(s) ? If so, these conditions must be given.

Comment: By the way, what is $\phi$ ? a constant? a function ?